# A doubt in the definition of the Lyapunov function

Tags: functions, lyapunov-functions

I've got the following definition (the definition of the function of lyapunov), but I don't understand it very well:

---

Let we have $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open where non $0 \in D$, $f_k \in C^1(D)$ where $f_k(0)=0$ for every $1\leq k \leq n$, $V\in C^1(D)$ and  $V':D \to \mathbb{R}$ being
$$V'(x)=\nabla V(x)\cdot f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\partial V(x)}{\partial x_k} f_k (x_1,...,x_n)$$
if $V$ is a positive definite function and $V'$ is a negative semidefinite function in $D$-n, $V$ is the Lyapunov function of the autonomous system $x'=f(x)$.

---

What I don't understand is, which is the relation between $f$ and $f_k$. Could anyone explain it to me, please??

Is it $f=(f_1,f_2,...,f_n)$ ??

Comment: Yes, it's simply $f=(f_1,\dots,f_n)$.